# Read a parquet.snappy file from AWS S3 React native

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, parquet, snappy

I am working on a app with react native and we are at a point where we need to read the parquet.snappy file from s3 bucket in react native app. is there any library for that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.